# URL wrongly updated?

Tags: bug

I typically view recent C questions using a page with the URL

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c
```

Starting today, when I click on a question to view it, I do see the question, but for some reason the browser address bar is still

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c
```

This makes it hard to bookmark questions, and means that an attempt to refresh the questions goes back to the C questions list.

Browser is Safari 11.0.2, if it makes a difference. {Update: this was entirely a Safari issue; no SO bug at all.]

It's happening here on Meta, too.  (For example, for me, this very page seems to have the URL `https://meta.stackoverflow.com`, although it's really `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391711/url-wrongly-updated`.)

Comment: No repo in Win 10, Chrome v78.0.3904.97 or Firefox v68.0.2

Answer (score 7):

That's not a bug. Or if it is a bug, it's Safari's.

Safari obfuscates the URL on the address bar, showing you only the domain name.

I guess they call it a *feature*, but I'm going to disagree on that.

In any case, it's a user selectable setting.

Check your preferences:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, but I've been using Safari to read SO for years, and it didn't start doing this until today.

Comment: It's a setting. Maybe you changed it by accident.

Comment: Well, I had never been to that Preferences page in my entire life, but I guess it did get changed somehow, because when I went there just now it was unchecked, and after checking it the address bar is starting to -- sometimes -- work again.  (But not always -- after turning it on and off several times to experiment, I'm now in a state where the address bar is wrong no matter what.)  Strange.  Thanks for your help.  (Pretty useless question now, though -- do you think I should delete it?)

Comment: And in the end, this wasn't it -- Safari was just very, very confused.  A restart seems to have properly fixed.  (Under normal circumstances, even without "Show full website address" checked, if you use your mouse on the address bar, the full URL appears.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Safari probably did something that either cleared your existing setting, or it was a new setting and they provided a bad default. I remember when Chrome and Firefox grayed out things that weren't the domain name and completely hid the "http" or "https" part, much to my annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it turns out that Safari was just completely borked.  At first, @yivi's answer involving the "Show full website address" preference *seemed* to be on the right track, but further investigation revealed that it was basically a red herring.

What the "Show full website address" preference does if not selected:

- at rest, the address bar shows just the hostname
- if you click the mouse in the address bar (to copy the address, or to edit or type in a new address) it adjusts to show the full address

What I was seeing:

- the URL in the address bar was just wrong (right hostname, but wrong path)
- setting or unsetting the "Show full website address" preference randomly affected this, or didn't
- Safari was so confused that the Quit selection was greyed out in the main menu (I had to use kill(1) from a Terminal window to kill it)

Sorry if this wasted anyone's time.